# Map<String, List<? extends T>> in Scala

Tags: scala, covariance, scala-collections

In my use case I have a class with covariant type Foo[+T] and classes A <: T, B <: T, C <: T,
I need to store a map "A" -> a Foo[A] instance, "B" -> a Foo[B] instance and "C" -> a Foo[C] instance, is this possible in scala?

Currently I declare my map as Map[String, Foo[T]]] but then I can't add a Foo[A] inside, i'm being told by the compiler that Foo[T] is expected, not Foo[A], which seems caused by the lack of covariance of the Map parameter, is there a solution?

My workaround for now is to de-parameterize Foo and cast in the code, which of course doesn't please me, I saw also that I could use java collections instead but I would prefer staying with scala.

Thanks in advance for your time

Comment: are you talking about mutable or immutable maps? with immutable maps, the value type is covariant...

Comment: oh right, I was in fact using HashMap implementation as a stupid reflex from Java which is wrong in scala, and HashMap is not covariant ><

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Works for me, even with non-covariant mutable Maps.

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.9.1.RC1 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_24).

scala> class T
defined class T

scala> class A extends T
defined class A

scala> class Foo[+T]
defined class Foo

scala>   val m = collection.mutable.Map[Int, Foo[T]]()
m: scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,Foo[T]] = Map()

scala>   val m2 = m + (1 -> new Foo[A])
m2: scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,Foo[T]] = Map(1 -> Foo@48f2818d)

scala>   m += (2 -> new Foo[A])
res0: m.type = Map(2 -> Foo@12caa79c)
```

If `Foo[T]` was not covariant in `T`, then the last command (`m += (2 -> new Foo[A])`) would fail.

Note that this code works because Tuples are also covariant in their types.

Comment: yes sorry, the problem I posted was different than the problem I had in my code because I still have the Java Reflex Map interface -> HashMap implementation which is wrong in scala since Map is covariant but not HashMap, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, the Java type `Map<String, List<? extends T>>` is written as:

```
Map[String, List[_ <: T]]
```